# What would happen if I change PATH_MAX and NAME_MAX in limits.h?

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel

The linux kernel defines `PATH_MAX` and `NAME_MAX` in `limits.conf`.

What would happen if I increase those constants and recompile the kernel?

Also, I believe I would have to change it in `/usr/include/linux/limits.h` and recompile libc (and any program that includes the header).

1. Would I be able to create files with longer paths/names?
2. What would happen if I mount a filesystem with those long filenames on another system?

For question 2:
I know the kernel will keep you from creating files where the path is more than `PATH_MAX`.
However, I wonder how it handles when the filesystem itself is providing it with a path longer than that (e.g. after an `ls`).

Answer (score 2):

1. It is already possible to create files with longer paths. By using relative paths, changing mount points etc. you can create files with absolute paths longer than `PATH_MAX`, and the kernel already knows how to deal with that. Increasing `PATH_MAX` (in [`include/uapi/linux/limits.h`, not `limits.conf`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0.2/source/include/uapi/linux/limits.h)) will increase the maximum path length you can process at a time. The Hurd famously [doesn’t even define `PATH_MAX`](https://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/community/gsoc/project_ideas/maxpath.html).

   Increasing `NAME_MAX` won’t necessarily help much because you’ll run into file system limitations; most file systems in use on Linux [support 255-byte component names only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits).
2. As mentioned above, longer paths are already a fact of life, and Unix-style systems cope with them (using relative paths, symlinks etc.). Longer *names* can also occur, and calls such as [`readdir`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html#NOTES) are documented as capable of returning names longer than the expected maximum.

See also [To what extent does Linux support file names longer than 255 bytes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/619625/86440)

Note too that programs shouldn’t use the build-time constants from `limits.h`, they should query limits using [`pathconf`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pathconf.html). Unfortunately that’s not always the case, and there’s a good chance you’d run into issues with a kernel assuming larger values of `PATH_MAX` and `NAME_MAX` when writing to buffers provided by userspace programs without a specified length.